# Property "groups" is not public in class "Backend\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuario". Maybe you should create the method "setGroups()"?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have this problem and I can´t resolve it. I'm newbie in Symfony 2.
I explain my problem. I have a Usuario class and Group class. I have overwritten the RegistrationForm to add group to users.

This is my code

```
<?php

namespace Backend\UsuariosBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        // agrega tu campo personalizado
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label'=>'Nombre Completo de usuario:'));

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // agrega tu campo personalizado
        $builder->add('roles', 'choice', 
                            array('label' => 'Elige un Rol para el usuario', 'required' => true, 
                                'choices' => array( 1 => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 2 => 'ROLE_USER'), 
                                'multiple' => true))
                ->add('groups', 'entity', array(
                            'label' => 'Asociar al Grupo de',
                            'empty_value' => 'Elija un grupo para el usuario',
                            'class' => 'BackendUsuariosBundle:Group',
                            'property' => 'name',
                        ))


        ;
    }



    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mi_user_registration';
    }
}
```

And my Usuario class is this:

```
<?php

namespace Backend\UsuariosBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use \FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Usuario")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email")
 */
class Usuario extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Por favor, introduce tu nombre.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit="3", message="El nombre es demasiado corto.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="50", message="El nombre es demasidado largo.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Backend\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Agrega un rol al usuario.
     * @throws Exception
     * @param Rol $rol 
     */
    public function addRole( $rol ) {
        $this->roles = array();
        if($rol == 1) {
          array_push($this->roles, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
        }
        else if($rol == 2) {
          array_push($this->roles, 'ROLE_USER');
        }
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add groups
     *
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function addGroup(GroupInterface  $groups)
    {
        $this->groups[] = $groups;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove groups
     *
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface $groups
     */
    public function removeGroup(GroupInterface  $groups)
    {
        $this->groups->removeElement($groups);
    }

    /**
     * Get groups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

Form shows correctly but at save show me this error:
*Property "groups" is not public in class "Backend\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuario". Maybe you should create the method "setGroups()"?*

Why? Some help/ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your inexperience could extend to PHP and programming in general.
However, we're here to help you.

As error says to you (is a lucky case when the error is really speaking) you're missing a method called `setGroups()`

You should implement it, in the following way

```
    /**
     * Set groups
     *
     * @param Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $groups
     * @return Usuario
     */

    public function setGroups(ArrayCollection  $groups)
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;

        return $this;
    }
```

This method is deeply different from existing method of your class, called `addGroup`; with `addGroup` you extend existing array of groups, whereas with `setGroups()` you put all groups into an ArrayCollection and, if other groups previously was associated, they will be overwritten.

Symfony2 form engine will work, by default, with `setXXXX` (where XXXX is property you're going to add) methods so is vital to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

@DonCallisto is somewhat right, but your issue is easier to fix and has a different cause.

Also, if you add a setGroup(), then you risk running into an issue with an `ArrayCollection` vs a `PersisitentCollection` later down the road. The fixes for that become messy.

What Symfony is expecting here, is for you to have the methods `addGroups()` and `removeGroups()`. *Plural*. You have `addGroup()` and `removeGroup()`.

I believe this happens if you generate the getters/setters/adders BEFORE you added these lines, which tell Symfony to treat it in multiples:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Basically, it thought you would only ever be expecting ONE group at a time, so it set up the getters/setters grammatically. This was changed and so has Symfony's grammar usage, but the method names have stayed the same.

Answer (score -1):

it's automapping maybe you can add:

```
    /**
     * Add groups
     *
     * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setGroup(GroupInterface  $groups)
    {
        $this->groups[] = $groups;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: I learned something ! I didn't really knew the difference between these two function... Thanks

Comment: @Freenando: if this answer satified you, please upvote and accept it for community sake :) thank you.

Comment: I haven´t got enough reputation for this :( sorry. I did it yet