# Symfony2: Form throws "Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given" on submit

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in one of my projects.

I've build a form based on the object Employee (that has manytomany with RoleGroup).

Here is the form (part of it):

```
$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MMAAuthBundle:RoleGroup',
    'choices' => $this->groups,
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => 'Groups',
    'expanded' => true,
    'attr' => array("multiple" => true)
));
```

When I submit the form, I get this error in the Profiler:

```
    at ErrorHandler ->handle ('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in /home/mihai/intranet/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 528 and defined', '/home/mihai/intranet/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php', '47', array()) 
in /home/mihai/intranet/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php at line 47
```

How can I make the form return an `ArrayCollection`, not a `RoleGroup` object?

I had exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931624/property-groups-is-not-public-in-class-backend-usuariosbundle-entity-usuario) problem before, but now I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is currently **not** a multiple form and therefore passes a single `RoleGroup` object instead of an array of `RoleGroup` objects to the constructor of the `Collection`.

[`multiple`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) is a **form-option** ... and not an HTML-attribute. Therefore ...

```
$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
// This would only render a multiple="true" inside the fields HTML tag
'attr' => array("multiple" => true)
```

... should be ...

```
$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
// multiple option not wrapped by attribute is correct
"multiple" => true
```